# Update a column using stored procedure in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

I got a table in which a column named `items` and its value is  `''` which is around 1000 of rows, how can we query in  PostgreSQL using stored procedure to rename each items to a unique value like column with an incremental value i.e

```
 items0001, items0002, items003,.....items1000
```

Tried this but its not working

```
UPDATE product SET items=CASE
          WHEN items='' THEN  items='items'+1
          ELSE items123

          END
```

Comment: Have you tried something? If yes then, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your table has a primary key column named `id` the following should do it:

```
update product
    set items = new_items.new_item
from (
  select id, coalesce(items,'')||to_char(row_number() over (), 'FM00009') as new_item
  from product
) as new_items
where new_items.id = p.id
and product.items is null or product.items = '';
```

Comment: @dude: you didn't mention anything regarding null in your question. see my edit

Comment: @dude: apparently you are using an outdated version of Postgres (probably 8.3 or even older).

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE product SET items=CASE
      WHEN len(items)>0 THEN  items='items'+1
      ELSE items123

      END
```

Comment: The OP wants to update that column with an incremental value i.e items0001, items0002, items003, ...

Comment: but i got items like tanker,puzzles etc in the column name... i just want to update the row which has a value null

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE product SET items=CASE
          WHEN len(items)>0 THEN 'items' || somesequence.nextval
          ELSE items
          END